# RestAssured: can't add Content-Length header, fails with message that it's already present

Tags: java, rest-assured

I'm trying to make a test with file upload to server

This is the code:

```
given()
       .port(port)
       .formParam("metadata", metadata)
       .multiPart("file", FILE_NAME, expectedValue, "image/jpeg")
       .header("Content-Length", expectedValue.length)
```

The problem is in RestAssured, he doesn't add `Content-Length` header by itself, but my hardcoded header value validated in

```
org.apache.http.protocol.RequestContent.process(final HttpRequest request, final HttpContext context)
```

the problem is in this place:

```
if (request.containsHeader(HTTP.CONTENT_LEN)) {
    throw new ProtocolException("Content-Length header already present");
    }
```

This condition doesn't throw exeception only when `Content-Length` is not preset at all

Please advise, how i can workaround this problem.

Comment: Hiya, I don't seem to understand the question much
Do you want to pass the content-length or do not want to pass the content-length ?

Comment: i want to, but restAssured fails with exception.

Comment: Can you add log().all() and paste your complete output ? We should be able to see more details

Comment: `Request method: POST
Request URI: http://localhost:57921/files
Proxy:   <none>
Request params: <none>
Query params: <none>
Form params: metadata={"name":"image.jpg","relation":"INSURANCE_CASE","relationId":"mockedRelationId","description":"mockDescription","source":"_1C","origin":"ATTACHED"}
Path params: <none>
Headers:  Content-Length=13482898
    Accept=*/*
    Content-Type=multipart/form-data
Cookies:  <none>
Multiparts:  ------------
    Content-Disposition: form-data; name = file; filename = image.jpg
    Content-Type: image/jpeg

    [B@16ca4532
Body:   <none>`

Comment: and as the result:
ProtocolException: Content-Length header already present

Comment: this is the headers, when i remove explicit setup of Content-Length:

`Headers:  Accept=*/*
   Content-Type=multipart/form-data`

Comment: @WilfredClement i've added logs.